# After moving to the Activity through notifications, start making new Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

There is a problem in MainActivity runs a service that sends a notification stating that the application is running, after minimizing the application if you click on the notification then returns the previous Activity, everything is fine, but if not then run the application from a shortcut that creates a new Activity. 
If you do not pass through the notification, the Launch a shortcut returns the previous Activity.
What could be the problem?

code MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
static boolean isPlayingMain;
static boolean isPlayingLiquid;
static boolean isPlayingDubstep;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
static AudioManager am;
static CheckBox pdaStream;
Button btnNews;
static TitleAdapter titleAdapter;
static ViewPager mViewPager;
Boolean isInternetPresent;
ConnectionDetector cd;
static String selectStream;
public String stream_sel;
public int stream;
public boolean checker;
public static boolean track;
public boolean searchtrack;
SharedPreferences mSettings;
static TextView titleMusic;
static boolean replay = false;
private MusicIntentReceiver myReceiver;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    titleAdapter = new TitleAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(titleAdapter);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(stream);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    pdaStream = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pdaStream);
    am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    SeekBar music = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    initBar(music, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            isPlayingMain = false;
    isPlayingLiquid = false;
    isPlayingDubstep = false;

    titleMusic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleMusic);
    titleMusic.setSelected(true);
    titleMusic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
    myReceiver = new MusicIntentReceiver();
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);

    startService(new Intent(this, MediaService.class));
}
```

Code MediaService:

```
public class MediaService extends Service implements OnPreparedListener,OnCompletionListener{

    static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
static NotificationManager nm;
private static NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
public static Context ctx;
    String titleNotif = "Station";
String contentNotif = "Running";

    public int onStartCommand(Intent paramIntent, int paramInt1, int paramInt2)  {

    try    {
          TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(0);
          notif(titleNotif, contentNotif);
          return super.onStartCommand(paramIntent, paramInt1, paramInt2);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException localInterruptedException)    {
          for (;;)      {
            localInterruptedException.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
}


public void notif(String titleNotif, String contentNotif){

    //building the notification
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.spy)
    .setContentTitle(titleNotif)
    .setTicker(contentNotif)
    .setOngoing(true);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    //Notification n = mBuilder.build();
    //nm.notify(1, n);
    startForeground(1, mBuilder.build());

}
```

Comment: you can mark your activiy as singletop activity on androidManifet

Comment: you can add flags..clear top and new task..with intent to launch new activity..in notification